# Put geocoded address to an input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textfield, reverse-geocoding

I have this input field

```
<input type="text" id="location">
<button id="getLocation">Get Location</button>
```

In My js

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#getLocation').on('click', function(){
              if (navigator.geolocation) {
                  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
              } else { 
                this.location = 'Geolocation is not supported by this device';
              }
         });

          function showPosition(position) {
            console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude);
            console.log("Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
            var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(position.coords.latitude), lng: parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)};
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
              if (status === 'OK') {
                if (results[1]) {
                  console.log(results[1].formatted_address);
                  $('#location').val(results[1].formatted_address);
                } else {
                  window.alert('No results found');
                }
              } else {
                window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
              }
            });
          }

        });
```

When I do this `console.log(results[1].formatted_address);` it shows the address in the console, but it when I do this `$('#location').val(results[1].formatted_address);` it doesn't display on the input text field.

How can display this -> `results[1].formatted_address` on the input textfield `<input type="text" id="location">`

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: can you show what is the o/p of `console.log(results[1].formatted_address);`

Comment: your current address

Comment: okay but i am asking bcz i tested with dummy data its working fine then the issue will be in data.